# How can I create frames stitched in a single image for jQuery animation?

Tags: jquery, animation

I want to use stiched frame animation to animate my images similar as to what [this plugin does](http://demo.dev.bitami.com/jQuery/frameanimation/) ([demo](http://demo.dev.bitami.com/jQuery/frameanimation/demo.html)).

So I created my stiched frames image with Photoshop by placing each in the correct position, it is a very dificult and timeconsuming, and I made a couple of mistakes ([here is my demo](http://www.primusgaming.com/klipanim)) so my question is: Is there a tool or a Photoshop plugin or something that would automatically stitch my images together so I dont have to do it manually? Is there like a Plugin for Photoshop that would export my animation as a single stiched image instead of say a GIF or a MOV?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Photoshop, depending on your version, they have a window panel called **timeline** or **animation**.  You can set each frame as a different layer, position them perfectly and test the animation without having to output everything first.

Once you get your animation perfect, you can export every frame in any manner you would like. When you are finished with your animation and each frame is set as a layer, you can then go to **File > Scripts > Export Layers to Files**. In that window, you can then set to export anywhere with any prefix and as any file type.  This should make it easier for you to do your animations.

Also, when referring to "Stitched" that is usually a term that designers use for things such as panorama shots, where you need to put one image next to the other and fade the edges so they actually are "stitched" together like cloth,  instead of being a frame-by-frame animation, more flip book style.

I know that is what they are calling it and I understand they are calling it that because you can technically "stitch" 35mm (or other) film together, but I think there may be more confusion than not by calling it stitched.

**UPDATE**

Step 1.  I'm assuming you've edited all of the images and saved them all as .PNGs.  I'm also assuming you've saved every one of them with the same width and height.

Step 2.  In Photoshop, go to **File > Scripts > Load Files into Stack**. Browse for all of your saved images and click OK

Step 3.  Make sure all of your images have loaded directly in the center.  View each image by itself by holding `alt` and click on the eyeball in the layers pallet.  When you go through these one by one, you will be able to see if they are all in the same place.  If any of them bump, adjust it with the arrow keys

Step 4.  Time for math:  Take your total image height (the height of the document in pixels) and multiply it by the number of images. (i.e. If you have 10 images and your document height is 80px, Your outcome is 800)

Step 5.  Remember this number and then go to **Image > Canvas Size**.  Type in that number in the `height` box, then make sure you click on the `Up Arrow` anchor.  This will make sure that the extra height you are adding is added under the current document.  Click `OK`

Step 6.  I would suggest recording an action for this and giving the action a function key so you can do this over and over.  **Before you make this action** Click on your second layer.  This will make sure you don't record this action.  Then, Go to **Window > Actions** and click on the `New Action` button on the bottom of the panel.  Name it anything you will remember and select a function key that you can press over and over. Click Record.

Step 7.  Now, remember the original height of the document?  Move or Nudge your image down that many pixels.  Using my example above:  If the image was 80px, I will hold shift and hit the down arrow 8 times (Holding shift while nudging, nudges 10px at a time).  This will place this image 80px below the first image which will be exactly the next "Frame".

Step 8.  Press `STOP RECORDING` on the actions panel (small square on the bottom left of the panel)

Step 9.  Select your third layer and press your function key twice.  This will replay your action of nudging or moving the specific pixel amount each time you press it.  (i.e. 1st time 80px, 2nd time 80pm MORE, 3rd time 80px MORE, etc.)

Step 10.  Repeat this for each layer until you've placed each layer.

You will find that this places them all perfectly assuming step 1 was done correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but perhaps I did not make myself clear. What I need is the animation to be in a single image, like a reel, where all frames are in the same image, one over the other, like this: http://demo.dev.bitami.com/jQuery/frameanimation/images/logo.png. Now producing this image is not so hard, until you have like 40 frames or more, then it becomes rather difficult to produce, and i am asking myself if there is a way to attach them together (or "stitch" them together, if you will) automatically. Is there a way? Thanks!

Comment: Aah, I see.  I will write an update shortly to help you out.  I've been designing for over 13 years and there's about 90 ways to skin this cat.  I'll give you my opinion on the best way, though many people will think differently, I'm sure.

Comment: Actually, I need you to answer this question first.  Do you need these images to have transparency? Or can your images be on a white background?

Comment: Hello, thanks again for the reply! YES! YES TRANSPARENCY! YES YES YES! Definitively yes! in fact, my first example is a transparent PNG.

Comment: Edited.  It's a non-plugin way to do it.  It will be quicker to do it this way once you understand it than getting a plugin.  If you have to do this for 50+ objects, I would suggest writing a script.  I'm not sure if a plugin like this exists yet.